# How to find a parent's ID through a child's ID

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically generated table that will have an ID. If the table has a radio button, when I click on the radio button I need to get that parent table's ID through javascript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery you can use `.closest()` or `.parent()` (though parent only looks up 1 level, whereas `.closest()` goes up until it find something).  I've always found `.closest()` easier and more robust, as it will work if you change the markup (i.e. you wrap stuff in a `<span>` or something).

Anyways, here's the jQuery version:

```
<input type="radio" onlick="var id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');" />
```

If you don't use a library, you can do this with just JavaScript as well.

The JavaScript:

```
function findAncestorByTagName(start, tagName) {
    if (tagName.toUpperCase() === start.nodeName.toUpperCase()) {
        return start;
    }
    else if (start === document.body) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return findAncestorByTagName(start.parentNode, tagName);
    }
}
```

The onclick handler you'll have to add:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="var par = findAncestorByTagName(this, 'div'); if (par && par.id) { /* use par.id */ }" />
```

Comment: your answers is very good but will it work for gridview server radio button

Comment: Nice one Dan, they do well as one-liners aswell (i made a find ancestorById aswell) - 
http://jsfiddle.net/squadjot/dz8Us/1/

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery can get the Parent of an element by element.parent(). So when you want the id from the parent you can write element.parent().attr("id);